# How can I use Pivot Table for this database?

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, pivot-table, unpivot

I couldnt use Pivot Table for this database.

I have a database like this:

| Date | power art | unit | energy_1 | energy_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | Number of power feeding systems | Number | 100 | 100 |
| Jan | net rated power | MW | 100 | 100 |
| Jan | power feed | KwH | 100 | 100 |
| Feb | Number of power feeding systems | Number | 100 | 100 |
| Feb | net rated power | MW | 100 | 100 |
| Feb | power feed | KwH | 100 | 100 |

But I would get this:

| Date | energy sources | Number of power feeding systems | net rated power | power feed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | energy_1 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| Jan | energy_1 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| Jan | energy_1 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| Jan | energy_2 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| Jan | energy_2 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| Jan | energy_2 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| Feb | energy_1 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| Feb | energy_1 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| Feb | energy_1 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| Feb | energy_2 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| Feb | energy_2 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| Feb | energy_2 | 100 | 100 | 100 |

Comment: What's the name of your RBMS?

Comment: TSQL (Transaction-SQL )

Comment: Do you need duplicates rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DataSource;

CREATE TABLE #DataSource (
    [Date] NVARCHAR(10),
    [power_art] NVARCHAR(50),
    [unit] NVARCHAR(10),
    [energy_1] INT,
    [energy_2] INT
)

INSERT INTO #DataSource
VALUES
('Jan', 'Number of power feeding systems', 'Number', 100, 100),
('Jan', 'net rated power', 'MW', 100, 100),
('Jan', 'power feed', 'KwH', 100, 100),
('Feb', 'Number of power feeding systems', 'Number', 100, 100),
('Feb', 'net rated power', 'MW', 100, 100),
('Feb', 'power feed', 'KwH', 100, 100)


SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT [Date],
           'energy_1' AS [energy_sources],
           [power_art],
           [energy_1] AS [Value]
    FROM
        #DataSource

    UNION ALL

    SELECT [Date],
            'energy_2' AS [energy_sources],
           [power_art],
           [energy_2] AS [Value]
    FROM
        #DataSource
) DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([value]) FOR [power_art] IN ([Number of power feeding systems], [net rated power], [power feed])
) PVT
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would typically need to unpivot the two energy columns, then pivot on the power art.

Here is one way to do it with `cross apply` and conditional aggregation:

```
select t.date, e.energy_source,
    max(case when t.power_art = 'Number of power feeding systems' then e.val end) as number_of_power_feeding_systems,
    max(case when t.power_art = 'net rated power'                 then e.val end) as net_rated_power,
    max(case when t.power_art = 'power feed'                      then e.val end) as power_feed,
from mytable t
cross apply ( values ('energy_1', energy_1), ('energy_2', energy_2) ) e(energy_source, val)
group by t.date, e.energy_source
```

Note that unpivoting with `cross apply` results in a single table scan, as opposed to other solutions using `union all`.